# Editores em tempo real de html, css e javascript offline

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor

Eu tenho usado muito editores em tempo real como [codepen.io](http://codepen.io) e [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), porém eles são online, eu pesquisei sobre alguns programas offline e a maioria deles são pagos ou não fazem o mesmo serviço, vocês sabem alguma alternativa gratuita e offline para esses editores?

Comment: Bom, não seria o caso de criar o arquivo *HTML* e abrir no navegador ? E atualizar quando fizer alterações no mesmo?

Comment: como o @NoobSaibot comentou, use um editor free como *Notepad++* ou *Sublimetext* por exemplo e abra no navegador, simples, prático e grátis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recomendo:** [VisualStudioCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)
E também você pode usar a extensão para o google chrome [Web Maker](https://webmakerapp.com/) ela funciona offline é baseada no [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) e é possível salvar o projeto em arquivos mesmo estando offline.